# Server 2008 does not retain named streams when zip archive is used

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

A retiring 2003 file server was/is used by our design group. This server has a share that is mounted using SMB from the Macs. Fonts are stored on this share and then archived using zip.exe from another server. With the right switch on the zip.exe the resource forks (named streams) are maintained in the zip archive.

With a newer 2008 file server this same process doesn't work. The files with named streams are fine for daily use but they do not archive correctly. The streams are lost and the needed files are corrupt when restored from archive.

One thing that has been noticed is the files with resource forks all show as zero K on the 2008 share when they are copied to the server. Then in just under a minute the file size increases to what it should be. Some sort of delay in creating the named stream occurs when files with resource forks are transferred. This does not happen on 2003 as the size is right almost instantly. This delay I suspect to be giving giving the zip.exe problems and some type of access is not granted quickly enough during the archive process.

What can be done to force 2008 to behave like 2003 in regards to creating/storing the resource fork/named stream? What is causing this delay?

Comment: Have you tried a different archive utility?  7zip comes to mind immediately, as being free for commercial use, [available on Mac and PC](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html), and being script/commandline friendly.

Comment: I don't think 7zip supports ADS though I could be wrong.

Comment: Just tried 7zip. It produces the same result. So, from a 2003 share the archive in intact and usable. From a 2008 share the archive is missing the streams(corrupt) and is not usable.

Answer (score 0):

At the root level of the share on the 2003 server this file is seen:
.com.apple.smb.streams.off

At the root level of the share on the 2008 server this file is seen:
.com.apple.smb.streams.on

Changing this file to match the 2003 setup - .off - archives using either zip application retain the streams. The display of file size after copies to server are almost instant also.

Thanks for the suggestions.